# Node.js: Requiring a class does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Hi I am trying to create a node.js server using es6 classes. 
For some reasons requiring my server class does not work and I can't figure out why it does not work.

PS: requiring the configuration works as expected.

**Node version:** 5.7.0

**Server.js:**

```
"use strict"
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')



class Server {

    constructor(configuration) {
        this.title = "Points Dashboard";
        this.app = express();
        this.configureAuthentication(configuration)
    }

    listen(port, callback) {
        this.app.listen(port, callback);
    }
}

module.exports = Server;
```

**app.js:**

```
"use strict"

const configuration = require('./lib/configuration');
const Server = require('./lib/Server')

const server = new Server(configuration)

server.listen(configuration.server.public_port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on ${configuration.server.public_url}, internal port ${configuration.server.public_port}`)
})
```

**Error:**

> TypeError: Server is not a function
>
> ... callstack
>
> at Object. (/root/app.js:6:16)

**Project Strcuture:**

[image]

**Debug log:**

[image]

Comment: is server.js inside currentdir/lib?

Comment: @Karim yes, because configuration and Server are both in lib and requiring configuration works

Comment: Have you tried to debug what Server equals to?

Comment: @estus Yes, I get a plain Object. I added a Debug Screenshot.

Comment: Where does `configureAuthentication` come from? Looks like its not defined.

Comment: @MartinGottweis you are right in my provided code it's not defined. The server class was bigger but I reduced it to a minimum. I forgot to remove configureAuthentication.

Comment: For what it's worth if I comment out the `configureAuthentication` and hardcode port and url in the `app.js` it is working just fine here. My node version is 5.9.1. Maybe try removing as much code as you can and try if it still throws this error.

Comment: agree to @MartinGottweis. I've tested your code without `configuration` and everything works fine. So I think a problem is somewhere in `this.configureAuthentication(configuration)`

Comment: @R_Valdez could you comment out the `configureAuthentication` and see if it runs? Then you could post the code for `configureAuthentication` if you can't find an issue there.

Comment: @MartinGottweis I will try it

Comment: @MartinGottweis I found the error and posted a explanation.

Comment: @R_Valdez Good job for fixing it.

Comment: @MartinGottweis I am thankful for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the error and it's really a stupid one. 
The code I posted above is correct. Something I didn't mentioned in this question is, that I am using docker. While writing my docker file i forgot to add a line to sync the code on my local machine with the code running inside the container. At the time I created the container I forgot to add `module.exports = Server;` that's the reason why require did not work.

I am using visual studio code to debug my code inside the docker container, but since I never changed something in app.js I couldn't see that the code running inside the container where different from my local code.

Thanks for your help!